# Cannot find '.Net Desktop Development' project template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a Windows Form Application in VS 2019, but for some reason can't find the option.

[image: Windows Form Application Missing]

".NET Desktop Development" Workload is installed, but not appearing in the list of project templates as it should.

[image: .NET Desktop Development Installed]

I have already updated the VS 2019 Application to the latest version as well.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2019 are you running? Code? Community? Professional? Enterprise?

Comment: Running Visual Studio 2019 Community

Comment: [Visual Studio 2019 - Create a Windows Forms App project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-1-create-a-windows-forms-application-project?view=vs-2019). -- [Compare Visual Studio 2019 Editions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/)

Answer (score 0):

Type Windows Forms Application (.Net Framework) or Windows Forms Application (Dot Net Core).